# Exception BadParametersError, can anyone resolve this?

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am seeing the above exception.
BadParametersError: Parameter s were incorrect. We wanted `{"required":["using","value"]}` and you sent `["using","value","locator"]` on Appium 1.5.3

Here is the code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//UIAStaticText[1]")).sendKeys(username);
```

Here it shows in logs:

```
POST /wd/hub/session/97e88008-b8e7-4c70-80b9-101d9b7c138f/element {"using":"XPath","value":"//UIAStaticText[1]","locator":"XPath"}
```

Please let me know if anyone has faced this issue and has any solution for this, this was working fine with Appium 1.4.8 earlier.

Comment: I reverted back to Appium 1.4.13 and it is working fine, seems an issue with latest appium.